# How copy files with a full route listed in listbox

Tags: vb.net, file-io, listbox

I have a list of full files that I want copy to other route. IE:

```
    c:\adsd\asdasd.txt
    c:\macarena\aaaahhhh.ogg
```

Then I want copy them into other route but all in same folder. IE:

```
    J:\
```

But I can't manage for do it. This is my actual function for it:

```
Function copyfiles(destiny As String)
    Dim totalfiles As Integer = ListBox2.Items.Count()
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Do While x <= totalfiles
        System.IO.File.Copy(ListBox2.Items.Item(x), destiny, False)
        x= x + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

When I try use this code I take an error warm me about it can't find route 'J:\' but it really exists and even I have it opened. I even tryed other drives with no luck. Always same error.

What can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify filename for destination file. Try this:

```
Private Sub copyfiles(destiny As String)
    Dim totalfiles As Integer = ListBox2.Items.Count()
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Do While x <= totalfiles - 1
        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(ListBox2.Items.Item(x))
        fi.CopyTo(destiny & fi.Name)
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

remember to pass `destiny` parameter with ending backslash: for example `j:\destination\`